# Android track ringtones

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Is there any way to receive a notification when each time ringtone is played? Lets say I want to do something after 2 rings. How can I achieve that?

Right now using PhoneStateListener I can get "ringing" when first time it rings, but not consecutive rings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.

What you can do is monitor the 3 states `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE`,  `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` and `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

When you receive CALL_STATE_RINGING you start a timer and start checking every N milliseconds for the current state. If it is still CALL_STATE_RINGING and you have not received another state (like CALL_STATE_IDLE) you can assume it is the same call still ringing and perform the action you want.

Listening of the number of rings is not a good idea because it can be different from network to network or country to country. In my country, you can change the ring-tones people hear when calling you for custom (musical) tones.

Comment: "When you receive CALL_STATE_RINGING you start a timer and start checking every N milliseconds for the current state. If it is still CALL_STATE_RINGING and you have not received another state (like CALL_STATE_IDLE) you can assume it is the same call still ringing and perform the action you want."


I don't think that time tracking will work, since ring tone can have variable length.

I have a use case where we need to do something after _italic_ n _italic_ ring tones.

@s1m3n

Comment: I don't think you can, I'll monitor this to see if someone knows a way, just out of curiosity.